# Can I put a Class name in a ending tag </div>?

Tags: html

I'd like to keep my DIVS a bit more organized.

Can I put the class name in the opening and closing?

```
<Div class="Mine">
</Div class="Mine">
```

Comment: That's like someone wanting a hat for their butt.

Comment: @zer00ne Well Said!

Answer (score 2):

Quick answer: no.

It's not valid. A very common practice is to add a comment just after the closing div. This way it remains valid and is still beneficial to the code reader.

```
<div id="first">
  <div class="second">
    <p>second div content. place this content in a semantic tag!</p>
    <div class="third">
       <p>third div content. this one too!</p>
    </div> <!-- end third -->
  </div> <!-- end second -->
</div> <!-- end first -->
```

https://csscreator.com/node/32602

Comment: TIP: if you put the comment inside of the <div> then if you select and move the Div the comment comes with it. It's a little unorthodox but it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Only start tags may contain attributes.

You can follow the end tag with a comment. You can organise your HTML so there are not so many levels of nested element that you get confused.